# How to include non-python reference files in Azure Function?

Tags: python, reference, azure-functions

I have some Python code that references external `.ttf` font files. I can reference them by including them in the project root folder. I'd like to turn this code into an HTTP Triggered Azure Function.

I see [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior) that I can import external *Python* modules and files into a Function, but what about *non-Python* files?

**How are these referenced?**

- When Python code is run locally, they are referenced in the code as:

```
h1_font = ImageFont.truetype("DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf", h1_size)
h2_font = ImageFont.truetype("Ubuntu-Th.ttf", h2_size)
h3_font = ImageFont.truetype("Ubuntu-Th.ttf", h3_size)
footer_font = ImageFont.truetype("UbuntuMono-R.ttf", footer_size)
```

**What is the filepath when the app is published to Azure?**

- Here is how the folders are structured locally:

[image]

**Once published to Azure, the `.ttf` files are no longer accessible and Function fails**

**Note:** This is a Python Function running on Linux, not Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

My structure:

[image]

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    font = TTFont('HttpTrigger1/font.ttf')
    with open('HttpTrigger1/test.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
    return func.HttpResponse("The content is -----------------"+data)
```

**Original Answer:**

> How are these referenced?

Put it in the Project folder and use relative path. Then use it as before.

> What is the filepath?

Physical path of azure function app is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.

> Do I just include them in the root folder of the Function and publish?

Yes, just include them in the root folder and then publish the function app, and then you can use relative path to get them.

Comment: Edited OP for more clarity. The relative path when developing locally != the path when the Function is published to Azure. What is the path for Linux apps (no "D:" drive)?

Comment: @SeaDude I updated the answer, and there is no problem when deploying to Azure for testing. By the way, where do you use .ttf files and how to use .ttf files?

Comment: I had to specify the current folder `my-barcode-api/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf`. Nice! Thank you. I use the .ttf files to specify custom fonts for labels that the Function creates.