# Azure App Function in Python - Include Classes

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

When working with Azure App Functions inside of Visual Studio Code I would like to add python Classes to import into **init.py** by including their files?

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: @BowmanZhu these are our own custom classes?

Comment: relative import: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486646/how-to-include-non-python-reference-files-in-azure-function/65488072#65488072

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show how to import the classes under test file **outside** HttpTrigger1 function, classes under test file **inside** HttpTrigger1 function.

Here is my file structure, :

[image]

1. Import the class named Display in **init**.py under test file **inside** HttpTrigger1 function:

   ```
    from test import Display
   ```
2. Import the class named Display1 in yes.py under test file **inside** HttpTrigger1 function:

   ```
    from test.yes import Display1
   ```
3. Import the class named Display in **init**.py under test file **outside** HttpTrigger1 function:

   ```
    from ..test import Display
   ```
4. Import the class named Display1 in yes.py under test file **outside** HttpTrigger1 function:

   ```
    from ..test.yes import Display1
   ```

Comment: thank you, I'm understanding creating the subfolder to be a requirement

Comment: @ffejrekaburb Please mark the answer to end this question if it helps you. It is very important. If you are willing to mark the answer, people will be more willing to help you solve the problem. :)